# Using 3rd party .NET libs in mixed C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, managed-c++

I have a Windows C++ project which compiles with the `/clr` switch. 
To use the `Form` object I had to write

```
#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll> 
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
```

and then I could declare and use the `Form` object.

now I'd like to use Some DevExpress components. So I went into the properties of the project and added a reference to DevExpress.XtraEditors library
[image]

then in my code wrote

```
#using <DevExpress.XtraEditors.v14.1.dll>
```

but it tells me it cannot find such a lib, so I wrote

```
#using <C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 14.1\Components\Bin\Framework\DevExpress.XtraEditors.v14.1.dll>
```

for which I don't get an error, but I don't like to write full path.

Anyhow, after this I added

```
using namespace DevExpress::XtraEditors;
```

but when trying to declare a variable of type XtraForm

```
extern gcroot<XtraForm^> form;;
```

it tells me it doesn't know about such data type.

What am I doing wrong here?
What is the correct way to reference a 3rd party library to a mixed C++ project?

Any good articles are highly appreciated.

thx

Comment: what is the detail error message?

Comment: You'll need to de-tune the urge to use #using.  It is a rather problematic way to reference an assembly in general, particularly the .NET Framework ones because they are read from the wrong directory.  Just add the references to the dialog in your screenshot, that's all you need.  Do avoid `using namespace` in a .h file, just spell out the full class name.